# Assembler 8086 divide 32 bit number in 16 bit number

Tags: assembly, x86, division, x86-16

I try to divide 32 bit number in 16 bit number. 
For example 10000000h divide by 2000h.According the desgin I try to do I divide 
4 right digits with the divisor and then the 4 left digit by the divisor.

This is my code :

```
.DATA 
num dd 10000000h
divisor dw 2000h 

result dd ? 
remainder dw ? 

.CODE
main:

mov ax,@DATA    
mov ds,ax 

xor dx,dx
mov cx ,word ptr divisor
mov bx,offset num
mov ax,[bx]
div cx

mov bx,offset result 
mov [bx],ax 
mov bx,offset num
mov ax,[bx+2]


mov ax,[bx+2]
div cx 
mov bx,offset result 
mov [bx+2],ax
```

I got zero in variable result. Not sure if the  problem with the design of the divide or just a little mistake.

Comment: What size are you expecting for the result? Do you want a 32-bit result (packed into, *e.g.*, `dx:ax`)? Or just a 16-bit result that will be vulnerable to overflow?

Comment: 32 bit result  .I did not notice that result is only 16 bit I thought  to give the result 16 bit and the remainder another 16 bits parameter

Comment: benz, there are two answers to your question, you should accept an answer by clicking the gray checkmark ✔ (at the top left of the answer).

Comment: @benz - you need to divide the 4 left digits (upper 16 bits) first, then the 4 right digits (lower 16 bits) second. I explain this in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method below is similar to long hand division on pencil and paper, dividing a 2 digit numerator by a single digit divisor. For example 99/4:

```
    2 4    (quotient)
  -----
4 | 9 9
    8
    -
    1 9
    1 6
      -
      3    (remainder)
```

Start off with dx = 0 and ax = high order of numerator. After the first div instruction, the remainder in dx is what's left of the high order of the numerator for the second divide. This method could be enhanced to handle a numerator and quotient of any size, as long as the divisor is a 16 bit value.

```
num     dd      10000000h
dvsr    dw      2000h 
quot    dd      ?
rmdr    dw      ?
;       ...
        mov     cx,dvsr                ;cx = dvsr
        xor     dx,dx                  ;dx = 0
        mov     ax,word ptr [num+2]    ;ax = high order numerator
        div     cx                     ;dx = rem, ax = high order quotient
        mov     word ptr [quot+2],ax   ;store high order quotient
        mov     ax,word ptr [num]      ;ax = low  order numerator
        div     cx                     ;dx = rem, ax = low  order quotient
        mov     word ptr [quot],ax     ;store low  order quotient
        mov     word ptr [rmdr],dx     ;store remainder
```

Comment: Without an explanation of what the code does and how it does it, code dumps are not useful answers.

Comment: @CodyGray - forum got stuck while I was trying to include the comments. Fixed now.

Answer (score 5):

With the 16-bit `div` instruction, you need to put the upper 16 bits of the dividend into `dx` and the lower 16 bits in `ax`.  You've done the latter for the first `div`, but you set `dx` to 0, so you end up computing 0h/2000h, which is 0.

Instead, you want something like:

```
mov bx, offset num
mov ax, [bx]
mov dx, [bx+2]
mov cx, word ptr divisor
div cx
```

Of course, this only works as long as the result fits in 16 bits—if it does not, the `div` instruction will raise a #DE exception.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear I want to get the remainder and the result can be bigger than  16 bit.

Comment: @benz - the remainder is < divisor, so the remainder is limited to 16 bits if the divisor is limited to 16 bits. The quotient can be more than 16 bits (take a look at my answer for how to implement this).

Comment: If the result doesn't fit, `div` raises a #DE execption.  The manual for [`div`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/DIV.html) says: "CF, OF, SF, ZF, AF, and PF flags are undefined" after `div` (whether it raises an exception or not).  There is no way to disable the exception and get a wrapping 32b/16b => 16b quotient & remainder.  (This is exactly the same behaviour as for divisor = 0.)

Answer (score 1):

The code written in answer 1 is the only exact. I written similar code, that divide D1 by D2:

```
Function Div32Bit(D1:LongInt;D2:Word):LongInt; Assembler;

Asm
 LEA   SI,D1
 Mov   CX,[SS:SI]
 Mov   AX,[SS:SI+2]
{AX:CX contains number to divide by}
 Mov   BX,D2
{BX contains number that divide}
 XOr   DX,DX
 Div   BX
 XChg  AX,CX
 Div   BX
{CX:AX contains the result of division}
{DX contains the rest of division}
 Mov   DX,CX
{DX:AX contains the result of division and is the function's result}
End;
```

But this method isn't valid to divide two signed number.
To divide two signed number:

```
Function IDiv32Bit(D1:LongInt;D2:Integer):LongInt; Assembler;

Asm
 LEA   SI,D1
 Mov   CX,[SS:SI]
 Mov   AX,[SS:SI+2]
{AX:CX contains number to divide by}
 Cmp   AX,32768
 CmC
 SbB   SI,SI
 XOr   CX,SI
 XOr   AX,SI
 Sub   CX,SI
 SbB   AX,SI
{AX:CX contains the absolute value of the number to divide by}
 Mov   BX,D2
{BX contains number that divide}
 Cmp   BX,32768
 CmC
 SbB   DX,DX
 XOr   BX,DX
 Sub   BX,DX
{BX contains the absolute value of the number that divide}
 XOr   SI,DX
{SI contains the sign of division}
 XOr   DX,DX
 Div   BX
 XChg  AX,CX
 Div   BX
{CX:AX contains the absolute value of the result of division}
{DX contains the absolute value of the rest of division}
 XOr   AX,SI
 XOr   CX,SI
 Sub   AX,SI
 SbB   CX,SI
{CX:AX contains the result of division}
 Mov   DX,CX
{DX:AX contains the result of division and is the function's result}
End;
```